# Flutter notification/value provider across widget tree

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I have the following views:

- SettingsView (Stateless) - updates SharedPreferences on ToggleButton.
- HomeView (Stateful) - Displays an TestWidget if the SharedPreference has the value true (say PREF_DEBUG)

The SettingsView is called using Navigator from a menu. I need HomeView to be notified whenever the value of SharedPreference is toggled (true/false).

Here is what I have, but either it does not work or I get context not available.

```
// home_view.dart
class HomeView extends StatefulWidget {
  _HomeViewState createState() => _HomeViewState();
}

class _HomeViewState extends State<HomeView> {
   bool _shouldShowDebugWidget = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((prefs) => setState(() => _shouldShowDebugWidget  = prefs.getBool(DefHelper.PREF_DEBUG) ?? false));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    final children = <Widget>[buildAlwaysShowingWidget()];
    if (_shouldShowDebugWidget) {
     children.add(buildDebugWidget());
    }

    return Scaffold(
        appbar: CustomAppBar(),
        body: Row(children: children)
    );

   }
}
```

```
// custom_app_bar.dart

class CustomAppBar {
   // on menu navigate and *not* PushReplacement.
   // reason for push is since Settings always comes back to calling Widget without knowing where to pop back to. Also avoid passing named routes,etc. in arguments to keep it clean.
   Navigator.of(context).push( ... SettingsView());
}
```

```
// settings_view.dart

class SettingsView extends StatelessWidget {
  
@override
Widget build(context) {
  ValueListenableBuilder(
              valueListenable: developerState,
              builder: (context, value, child) {
                if (value) {
                  return ValueListenableBuilder(
                      valueListenable: debugState,
                      builder: (context, value, child) {
                        return ToggleSwitchLineView(
                          text: S
                              .of(context)
                              .title_debug,
                          initialLabelIndex: value
                              ? ToggleSwitchLineView.STATE_ON
                              : ToggleSwitchLineView.STATE_OFF,
                          onToggle: (state) {
                            // ** THIS IS FAILING WHEN TRYING TO USE PROVIDER / MultiProvider from main (multi-provider since I have a theme manager provider which the entire app consumes)
                            Provider.of<MySharedPreferencesProvider>(context, listen: false).setPreference(DefHelper.PREF_ADMIN_DEBUG, state);
                          },
                        );
                      });
                }

    // somewhere here user can navigate back to the MainScreen whose state is maintained.
}
}
```

How should I go about notifying the HomeScreen about the change in sharedpreference value even when HomeScreen is not in view. Would like to avoid callbacks since this could be nested deep down.

Comment: read about state managements in flutter https://docs.flutter.dev/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options

Comment: I am trying to use ModelBinding. Let's see how it goes.

@Qori - But any particular reason the Provider/Consumer scenario wouldn't work based on the code shared in OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried ModelBinding for this approach but the notifications would somehow not be propogated to the HomeView widget. I switched to Providers with ChangeNotifier and that seem to do the trick.

```
// my_preference_provider.dart

class MyPreferenceProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  final Map<String, dynamic> _preferences;

  MyPreferenceProvider({this._preferences});

  dynamic get (String key) => _preferences[key];

  void set(String key, dynamic value) {
    _preferences[key] = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

```
// main.dart

...
... build(BuildContext context) {
   return KeyedSubtree(
      key: key,
      child: MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ListenableProvider(create: (_) => AppThemeManager()),
          ListenableProvider(create: (_) => _preferenceModel)
        ],
          child: Consumer2<AppThemeManager, MyPreferenceModel>
            (builder: (_, themeManager, preferenceModel, __) {
            return MaterialApp( ... );
         }))
      );
}
...
```

```
// home_view.dart
class HomeView extends StatefulWidget {
  ...
}

class _HomeViewState extends State<HomeView> {

  ... build(context) {

    var children = [buildAlwaysShowingWidget()];
    final debug = Provider.of<MyPreferenceProvider>(context, listen: true).get(DefHelper.PREF_ADMIN_DEBUG);
   if (debug) {
      children.add(buildDebugWidget());
   }

    return Scaffold(
        appbar: CustomAppBar(),
        body: Row(children: children)
    );

  }
}
```